AppleScript that reduces the size of multiple PDF files fails
macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6.
Script-editor Version 2.9 (191).
I'm trying to reduce the size of multiple PDF files, however the script below exits wth this error: line ending expected, but class name found. The script also highlights line 19's word document.
-- Compress PDFs using Preview's Quartz Filters
set quartzFilter to "Reduce File Size" -- Replace with your Quartz filter name
set outputFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Select the folder to save compressed PDFs:")

tell application "Finder"
    set pdfFiles to (choose file of type "PDF" with prompt "Select PDF files to compress:" with multiple selections allowed)
end tell

repeat with pdfFile in pdfFiles
    set inputFilePath to (pdfFile as text)
    set outputFilePath to ((outputFolder as text) & (name of (info for pdfFile)))
    
    tell application "Preview"
        open pdfFile
        delay 1 -- Allow time for Preview to load the file
        try
            export document 1 to file outputFilePath as PDF using Quartz filter quartzFilter
            close document 1
        on error errMsg
            display dialog "Error processing file: " & (name of (info for pdfFile)) & ". Error: " & errMsg
        end try
    end tell
end repeat

display dialog "Compression complete!" buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"

So I decided to run the script from Terminal. However, testing on one file and then multiple files also failed.
Running the script for multiple files with the following command:
$ for file in /Users/Guest/Desktop/202410271045\ separated/*.pdf;
do
    output="${file%.pdf}_compressed.pdf";
    cupsfilter -i application/pdf -o "$output" -p /System/Library/Filters/Reduce\ File\ Size.qfilter "$file";
done

failed with loads of weird characters in the Terminal output.
This is the output when running the script with one file:
$ cupsfilter -i application/pdf -o /Users/Guest/Downloads/compressed.pdf -p /System/Library/Filters/Reduce\ File\ Size.qfilter /Users/Guest/Downloads/input.pdf
DEBUG: argv[0]="cupsfilter"
DEBUG: argv[1]="1"
DEBUG: argv[2]="Guest"
DEBUG: argv[3]="input.pdf"
DEBUG: argv[4]="1"
DEBUG: argv[5]="/Users/Guest/Downloads/compressed.pdf=true"
DEBUG: argv[6]="/Users/Guest/Downloads/input.pdf"
DEBUG: envp[0]="<CFProcessPath>"
DEBUG: envp[1]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/pdf"
DEBUG: envp[2]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
DEBUG: envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
DEBUG: envp[4]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/libexec/cups"
DEBUG: envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/private/etc/cups"
DEBUG: envp[6]="LANG=de_CH.UTF8"
DEBUG: envp[7]="PATH=/usr/libexec/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
DEBUG: envp[8]="PPD=/System/Library/Filters/Reduce File Size.qfilter"
DEBUG: envp[9]="PRINTER_INFO=cupsfilter"
DEBUG: envp[10]="PRINTER_LOCATION=Unknown"
DEBUG: envp[11]="PRINTER=cupsfilter"
DEBUG: envp[12]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
DEBUG: envp[13]="USER=Guest"
DEBUG: envp[14]="CHARSET=utf-8"
DEBUG: envp[15]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/pdf"
INFO: gziptoany (PID 5149) started.
DEBUG: Unable to open "/Users/Guest/Downloads/input.pdf".
ERROR:Unable to open print file: No such file or directory
ERROR: gziptoany (PID 5149) stopped with status 1


There's quite a lot to unpack here:
Firstly, Automator has an Apply Quartz Filter action, which is a lot easier to user than AppleScript. (Quartz Filters are an OS feature, not just Preview's.)
Secondly, the OS-bundled filter to Reduce file size is well-known for being terrible, and you can find various third-party filters that provide better settings. Or you can create your own filter in ColorSync Utility, as per my answer here.
Thirdly, Apple made a lot of changes to PDFKit in Sierra, and with that came many bugs in PDF creation and manipulation. Most of these were fixed in High Sierra, but some lingered until Mojave. Any Mac running Sierra should be capable of running High Sierra, at least.
If there's a compelling reason why you need to stay on Sierra, then I'd suggest downloading a compatible version of GhostScript, which should be able to batch-compress PDFs very easily.
Also, it looks like you're using a Guest user account? (Unless that's your name.) It's possible that a guest account has restricted permissions, which might cause problems.
As for the AppleScript itself, it looks like there's no such command as export in the Preview AS dictionary. (There isn't in Sonoma, at least: but you should check the dictionary in Sierra.)
One final thing about your shell script: The 'weird characters' in the Terminal output were actually the data contents of the PDF file being written to stdout. The -o flag passes options to the print driver; it doesn't set the output file. Also -p sets the PPD to be used. You can't apply a Quartz Filter to cupsfilter. (CUPS has its own 'filters', which are a completely different thing.)
Something that may be useful is this python script, which you can use on the command line to apply quartz filters to PDFs. It uses the system python2, so you don't need to install anything.
https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite/blob/master/legacy%20(python%202)/Shell_Scripts/quartzfilter.py
